# NSButton corner radius and NSPopover

Tags: macos, rounded-corners, nsbutton, nsstatusitem

I'm using an NSPopover and I'm putting a NSViewController inside to be displayed as a custom view from a NSStatusItem. Most of the view controller displays correctly except for the NSButton that have a corner radius on them. There is some extra white leaking out where the rounded corners are being applied. Displaying the buttons within the actual app, this problem doesn't occur.

I feel it has to do something with the NSPopover appearance which I have set to "NSAppearanceNameAqua".

The NSButtons are within a NSView which are displayed in a NSTableView and are set to this style.

```
    self.createdButton.wantsLayer = true
    self.createdButton.layer?.backgroundColor = Utils.blackColor().CGColor
    self.createdButton.layer?.masksToBounds = true
    self.createdButton.layer?.cornerRadius = 5
```

[image]
[image]

The top image is when the actual app is open.
The bottom image is when the view controller is being shown within a NSPopover.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the top image is when the actual app is open" vs "the view controller is being shown within a NSPopover" ? So the app isn't open in the bottom image?

Comment: I am creating a NSStatusItem that appears in the top menu bar. When you click the icon from the menu bar, an NSPopover appears with the view controller containing those buttons.

Comment: One thing that I found is if you add your buttons programmatically in the contentViewController and then round them they will round correctly. However, linking the same buttons/views from Interface Builder in a Xib/Storyboard will not apply the correct rounding, at least that was what I experienced. Maybe a bug in AppKit?

Comment: did you ever resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

create corner radius using bezier path  i.e.

```
    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:view.bounds xRadius:3 yRadius:3];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = view.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = path.toCGPath;
    self.containerView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```